# compare suppliers from 2 tables in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle12c

I have 2 tables

in both tables are suppliers with items. In the table supplier_with_awards are suppliers which can deliver an item. for 1 item there could be several suppliers. in the table suppliers_with_incomming_goods are suppliers that actually supply the items. There is a situation that non-awarded supplier supplies an item.

case 1
I need to check if the item is in both tables and pick up only those with different suppliers

case 2
same as case 1 but pick up non-awarded suppliers as well.

my data

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers_with_awards ( supplier, item ) AS
SELECT 'supplier1', 'item1'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'supplier2', 'item1'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'supplier3', 'item2'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'supplier4', 'item3'        FROM DUAL ;

CREATE TABLE suppliers_with_incoming_goods ( supplier, item ) AS
SELECT 'supplier1', 'item1'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'supplier2', 'item1'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'supplier5', 'item2'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'supplier6', 'item4'        FROM DUAL ;
```

with simple join we get for item1 unnecessary combinations supplier1-supplier2 and vica versa but in reality supplier1 got award and supplier1 delivers, the same goes for supplier2. So I used row_number to exclude such cross combo if you have better solution let me know.

```
with award as (
select supplier, item, row_number() over (partition by item order by supplier) r
from suppliers_with_awards
),
goods as (
select supplier, item, row_number() over (partition by item order by supplier) r
from suppliers_with_incoming_goods
)
select a.supplier,a.item,g.supplier from award a join goods g on a.item=g.item and  a.r=g.r and a.supplier<>g.supplier;

SUPPLIER    ITEM    SUPPLIER
supplier3   item2   supplier5
```

this query finds the item2 because there are different suppliers as I want (case 1).again if there is better solution for this , please ....
But I need somehow to get the non-awarded supplier6 with item4 as well (case 2)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current query may not return all results with inserted different values such as `supplier7` and `supplier8` for `item1` inserted into the table `suppliers_with_awards`. I don't recommend use analytic function in this case, rather you can convert the query into the following which includes `NOT EXISTS`. And use `UNION ALL`, since you may need to return more than two `supplier` which already should be independently listed each unique one into one seperate line

```
--# Case 1
WITH item_supplier AS
(
 SELECT g.item AS item,
        a.supplier AS supplier_a,g.supplier AS supplier_g
   FROM suppliers_with_awards a
   JOIN suppliers_with_incoming_goods g
     ON a.item = g.item
)
SELECT DISTINCT item, supplier_a AS supplier
  FROM item_supplier i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 
                      FROM item_supplier 
                     WHERE supplier_g = i.supplier_a)         
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT item, supplier_g
  FROM item_supplier i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 
                      FROM item_supplier 
                     WHERE supplier_a = i.supplier_g)
```

for the second case just convert the `INNER JOIN` to `RIGHT or FULL JOIN`, and filter out the `NULL` values of `item` and `supplier` in the main query such as

```
--# Case 2
WITH item_supplier AS
(
 SELECT g.item AS item,
        a.supplier AS supplier_a,g.supplier AS supplier_g
   FROM suppliers_with_awards a
  RIGHT JOIN suppliers_with_incoming_goods g
     ON a.item = g.item       
), its AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT item, supplier_a as supplier
  FROM item_supplier i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 
                      FROM item_supplier 
                     WHERE supplier_g = i.supplier_a)         
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT item, supplier_g
  FROM item_supplier i
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 0 
                      FROM item_supplier 
                     WHERE supplier_a = i.supplier_g) 
)
SELECT *
  FROM its                      
 WHERE item IS NOT NULL 
   AND supplier IS NOT NULL
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=736b23b035678915a1e93a9c0e8ab0c8)</kbd>